# SQL Подсчет колличества повторений в стобце

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть БД writing с именем автора(author_name) и его произведениями(writing_name).
Нужно вывести количество произведений каждого автора.
Вывод должен быть в формате author_name|number_of_writings

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Читать конспект по GROUP BY и по COUNT().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author_name, COUNT(author_name) AS  
'number_of_writtings' FROM writting /*если 
это имя таблицы*/
GROUP BY author_name;
```

Выбираем имя автора, подсчитываем, сколько раз оно встречается в таблице ( что и даёт количество различных произведений), группируем по имени автора.